# add more value on chart in vs 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

I have some sales data in mysql and after some query the result would be something like this:

```
year  |sales   |
2008  |100000  |
2009  |120040  |
2010  |239000  |
2011  |300900  |
2012  |200900  |
```

and this data will be shown on chart, now I want to add one value from some data forecasting for next year, and display it on chart

I've tried this code:

```
    myChart.Series[0].Points[0].XValue = (year + 1);
    myChart.Series[0].Points[0].YValues = dataForecasting;
```

but nothing happen, how can I add one value on chart? I want a continuous line graph, so from 2008 until 2013 there was only one series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    List<string> years = new List<string> { "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997" };
    List<double> yearSales = new List<double> { 10000.23, 98000, 95876, 78097 };


    Series yearSeries = chart1.Series.Add("sales");
    yearSeries.Points.DataBindXY(years, yearSales);
    yearSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    // do stuff....

    // add one more value

    years.Add("1998");
    yearSales.Add(12345.67);
    yearSeries.Points.DataBindXY(years, yearSales);
```

Comment: but I want a continuous line graph, so from 2008 until 2013 there was only one series, one line, but your code will add another data series

Comment: Well keep the values in an array, as in the example.  When you want to update the chart with a new datapoint on the same series, add the value to the existing array and re-call "thisYear.Points.DataBindXY" which will update the chart with the array, which will contain the extra value...